# Spark Framework : SLF4J: Failed to load class

Tags: java, eclipse, spark-java

I am trying to run a hello world application on Spark framework.
 Here is my code:

```java
public class App{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
        //System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is :

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

I was advised to add the relevent jars to class path , I've done so ... [class path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKkRz.png)  . but the error still persist when i run the application .

What should I do ?

Comment: Try to change the versions of Jar.
There is a documentation in [SLf4J site] (https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) which resolves this.